# Outlook javascript failing after update

Tags: javascript, c#, api, office-js

We are using the Office Plugin with the Office javascript API version 16.0.  After the update on August 13th to version 1907 (Build 11901.20218) for our Monthly Channel and version 1902 (Build 11328.20392) on our Semi Annual Channel users we are no longer getting the email address from the userProfile using the javascript API call to Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress.  This returns a null on every call.  Is anyone else experiencing this issue? Or know of a solution?  Thanks.

We have tried this on versions of Outlook prior to the August 13, 2019 update and the plugin works as expected.

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce this. Just to make sure on the JS version, are you using office.js from appsforoffice.com (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js)? Do you see issues with other APIs?

Comment: I will double check our office.js file.  It has been working for sometime before the 13th so not sure what would have changed.

Comment: I have tested this further using a physical machine with Outlook Version 1907 (11901.20218) and a Virtual machine using the same Outlook Version both on Windows 10.  On the virtual machine the Add-on works correctly.  On the physical machine the Add-in does not work as no data is being sent from the Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress.  Both machines are referencing the same Add-on with the same version of office.js and the same manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to reference the CDN office.js from appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js instead of a local version of the office.js